appwrite list.users search query
I am trying to use list.users to find the user id for a specific email from appwrite-dart package but it is not working.
previous question (appwrite list users search params) was answered stating that the search format is
list.users(search: Query.equal('email', 'user@domain.com'));
but this returns a list of what appears to be all users in domain.com. Although if I query Query.equal('email', 'Patrick') it seams to return a list of all users with Patrick somewhere in the profile. So I am not really sure what it is querying.
MY QUESTION:
how do i get the user id of a user with a specific email.
Thanks - Patrick

Try using list.users(queries: [Query.equal('email', 'user@domain.com')]);.

perfect, thank you @darshan
